# on page anchor scroll and offset header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I offset the height of a top nav while using secondary anchor for on page navigation?

I've used :target with padding. It works but when you scroll you see this extra padding between elements.

I tried js, but I think the window.scrollBy is happening before/during the anchor scroll. If I click multiple times in a row, it will eventually give the desired results...

How do I delay the scrollBy to happen after the anchor action?
http://codepen.io/jeffreyb42/pen/xqRRMY

```
$(function(){
  $('.side-nav').on('click', function(){
    window.scrollBy(0, -70);
    console.log("should have scrolled...")
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery code something like this:

```
$(function(){
 $('.side-nav li a').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();     
 var scrollTo=$($(this).attr('href'));    
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - $('.header').height()},
    'slow');
  });
```

});

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/mohit_maddan/pen/GWNWKN)**

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed :)

Comment: Now is there a way to do this when navigating between pages? My site has several pages with links between them. When using these anchors between pages, the h1 is behind the title bar.